# k3s separate control plane node. egress-selector-mode cluster doesn't work

Tags: k3s

I am looking for suggestions how to separate k3s control plane node from worker nodes. Something like konnectivity but since it's k3s which is only a single binary i prefer not to consider konnectivity. I try https://docs.k3s.io/installation/network-options#control-plane-egress-selector-configuration
--egress-selector-mode cluster mode but seems it's not doing the job i don't see the separation happening.

k3s control plane hidden from users and traffic between kubernetes apiserver and worker nodes is using tunnel.